# .htaccess file - can't get it working

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

My root is `www`. `www/css/` is subdirectory containing all css files.
I want the files (not the folders) from the root (www) to have access to the files in css (I'm using includes (php)). 
I dont want the user to have direct access to the files in the directory www/css/.

I have the following code in .htaccess file in subdirectory www/css/:

`Options FollowSymLinks
Deny from css`

I write it so because when I use the `<Directory>` tags it simply doesn't work (Internal Server Error).
However I block the access to the directory www/css but not to the files in it (for example I can access file www/css/grid.css).

When I say:

```
Deny from all
```

All files in the root (www) lose access to this files. As a result I have no css styling.

Can anyone help me out, please? I tried to solve this issue for 5 hours, and I couldn't. And I am still trying.

*Merry CHRISTmas!*

Comment: If you are using a FTP Client like FileZilla that allows you to set permissions for files and directories on your remote host. This function is often called chmod or set permissions in the program menu or By using the file manager provided in your host's control panel like cPanel, DirectAdmin, Plesk..Alternatively If you have shell/SSH access to your hosting account, you can use chmod to change file permissions.

Comment: And there is also a php function called chmod which i never used.http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: I tried it but it is not really what I am searching for.
With permission 711 (for example) I can allow everybody to execute the file at any time through the directory. And I want to block the direct access to this directory for users. (I dont want him to execute it at any time)

Comment: Why don't you give a readonly permission..Such as 644..And if you have a security consideration..It's secure..But if you want to hide your css file for a reason such as "stolen design"..An avarage user will never go to css path..And a front end developer will use tools such as "firebug"..

Answer (score 0):

Upload an `.htaccess` file to `http://example.com/www/css/`.

In the `.htaccess` file, include the lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ http://example.com/www/deny_css_access.html
```

If everything works (it ought to), then any attempt to access a `.css` file in `http://example.com/www/css/` by typing the address of that file directly into the browser bar, will simply result in the browser address bar redirecting to:

`http://example.com/www/deny_css_access.html`.

Comment: Ok I tried it and here what happens:
I can access the files in the `www/css/` directory, and when I refresh the page it directs me to `deny_css_access.html`

Comment: What is the address of the page you are refreshing?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the part of your question where you write: _" I dont want the user to have direct access to the files in the directory www/css/."_. The intention of the directive above is that - while your website pages can still refer to and access the stylesheets - you (as a user) will not be able to see any `.css` files in the `/www/css/` folder - and that if you try to point the browser at `.css` files in this folder, you will be redirected to `/www/deny_css_access.html`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: You've completely lost me. I had understood that you wanted your `.css` stylesheets to be accessible as normal from the pages on your website, but not directly accessible via the browser. I think I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I struggle with stackoverflow commenting//
I don't particurally mind someone seeing my css files. But it is interesting why it is working (the .htaccess block) for php files and not for css and js files (only the directories are being 403 errored but not the css and js files, actually works **only after Refresh**).

Comment: I see. But do the `mod_rewrite` directives I've posted above not work as they are meant to? If not, please state what is not working. Thanks.

Comment: This is the 'unexpected behaviour' of the code you posted:
I call the following http-query: `www/css/file.css`; I see the text in the the file (which I don't want to happen). After refreshing it directs me to the `deny_css_access.html` (index.php)
You can try it out on [link] (http://www.bstudent.uchenici.bg/css/grid.css)

Comment: @Ruth Busari..Why the php script isn't shown because it's a script..And when you go a route ex: www.example.com/index.php..The script runs and it transformed to html..And you see the html in the browser..If you have security considerations its enough too sure you have right file permission..(Sometimes not enough)..But if you really don't want to show your css html..There is some possible ways such as encrytp html,route to another directory..And even you can set a session with php on your css file..Then basic if else..But that's not the point of your question i guess..